# Read a dictionary list, within another dictionary list

Tags: python, json

I have the following Json file

```
{
  "AFB": [
    {
      "policy": [
        {
          "Systems": [
            {
              "icon": "icon_sys"
            },
            {
              "scripts": [
                "os_preg4",
                "os_preg14"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Sudo": [
            {
              "icon": "icon_sys"
            },
            {
              "scripts": [
                "sudo_preg4",
                "sudo_preg14"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "INFRA": [
    {
      "policy": [
        {
          "Systems": [
            {
              "icon": "icon_sys"
            },
            {
              "scripts": [
                "os_preg4",
                "os_preg14"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I try to read and go through a dictionary list, inside the other dictionary list, but I don't get what I want, what I want is to save the value of the icon in a variable, and in another variable the value of the scripts. for now I have this that if it works for me, it prints the client that I passed as a key and the policies, with their respective dictionaries, and I can no longer

```
import json

with open('/home/lopuma/Compliance/.conf/clientes.json') as op:
    data = json.load(op)
    for clt in data['AFB']:
        print("customer {}, policy {}".format('AFB',clt['policy']))
        for pol in clt['policy']:
            print("policy, en linea : ", pol)
            for sis_pol in pol:
                print("Sis : ", sis_pol)
                for policy in pol[sis_pol]:
                    lista = list(policy.keys())
                    print("list : ", lista)
```

I add the output of the command, but I don't know how to get only the value of the icon in one variable and only the value of each item in the list of scripts in another.

what I have tried is to go through the dictionary list to, show the result of a client and get its policies (key), within its policies, either sudo or systems, I want to get the value of icon in a variable and the in another variable the script value

**I NEED TO GET SOMETHING LIKE THIS**

I need to save to a variable, the icon, and the value of the script, for example:

```
Customer: "AFB"
------------------------- 
**policy 'Systems'**
--------------------- 
icon = "icon_sys" 
var_script = ["os_preg4", "os_preg14"]

**Sudo Policy**
--------------------- 
var_icon = "icon_sudo" 
var_script = ["sudo_preg4", "sudo_preg14"]
```

*And so with each of the clients, either AFB or INFRA*

Comment: I dont get fully your question, can you maybe add you want as output?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you need?

Comment: I need to save to a variable, the icon and script value, for example:
```
Customer: "AFB"
-------------------------                                                                                                
policy 'Systems'
---------------------                                                                                                              var_icon = "icon_sys"                                                                                              var_script = ["os_preg4", "os_preg14"]

Comment: @LOPUMAJoseAlvaroCedeño Please update your question with this information, it's hard to read as a comment.

Comment: 'Sudo' policy                                                                                                                  
 --------------------                                                                                                 
 var_icon = "icon_sudo"                
 var_script = ["sudo_preg4", "sudo_preg14"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code does what you asked for.

```
data = json.loads(op)

icons = []
scripts = []

for customer in data:
  print(f"{'_' * 50}\nCustomer: {customer}\n {'-' * 50}")
  
  for politica in data[customer][0]["politica"]:
    politica_key = list(politica.keys())[0]

    print(f"**Policy {politica_key}**\n {'-' * 50}")
    
    for item in list(politica.values())[0]:
      item_key = list(item.keys())[0]
      
      if item_key == "icon":
        print(f"Icon = {item[item_key]}")
      
      elif item_key == "scripts":
        print(f"Scripts = {item[item_key]}")
    
    print()
```

Output -

```
__________________________________________________
Customer: AFB
 --------------------------------------------------
**Policy Sistemas**
 --------------------------------------------------
Icon = icon_sys
Scripts = ['os_preg4', 'os_preg14']

**Policy Sudo**
 --------------------------------------------------
Icon = icon_sys
Scripts = ['sudo_preg4', 'sudo_preg14']

__________________________________________________
Customer: INFRA
 --------------------------------------------------
**Policy Sistemas**
 --------------------------------------------------
Icon = icon_sys
Scripts = ['os_preg4', 'os_preg14']
```

Comment: error : In json.loads(op)   :              data = json.loads(op)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'TextIOWrapper'

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: is a JSON file with the content of the question, I don't know how can I share??

Comment: added data = json.loads (op.read ()) and now I don't get the error, but I don't print everything, just print the last data

Comment: ```__________________________________________________
Customer: INFRA
 --------------------------------------------------
__________________________________________________
Customer: AFB
 --------------------------------------------------
**Policy Systems**
 --------------------------------------------------
Icon = icon_sys

Scripts = ['os_preg4', 'os_preg14']

**Policy Sudo**
 --------------------------------------------------
Icon = icon_sudo

Scripts = ['sudo_preg4', 'sudo_preg14']```

Comment: **Ok, it's already corrected, now if you print as it should**

Comment: Yh I tried on the JSON file you shared, it seemed to work for me. Thanks for accepting the answer!